# Add parent node by keeping the existing child node in existing xml file using Powershell-

Tags: xml, powershell

**Existing File** 
I have the below xml file. I want to use PowerShell to add the missing node.
I need help to generate the new XML file. Need help on that.

```
   <Office>
        <EmpID>0001</EmpID>
        <EmpName>John</EmpName>
        <Dept>HR</Dept>
        <Location>Ohio</Location>
        <Designation>Associate</Designation>

        <EmpID>0002</EmpID>
        <EmpName>George</EmpName>
        <Dept>IT</Dept>
        <Location>California</Location>
        <Designation>IT Engineer</Designation>

        <EmpID>0003</EmpID>
        <EmpName>James</EmpName>
        <Dept>Fin</Dept>
        <Location>NewYork</Location>
        <Designation>Auditor</Designation>
    </Office>
```

**New Expected file**

```
 <Office>
       <OfficeName>NEWOFFICE</OfficeName>
       <OfficeRegNuM>1234</OfficeRegNuM>
       <OfficeAddress>Building 001</OfficeAddress>
       <Employee> **#this is missing in existing file,How to add this Node
        <EmpID>0001</EmpID>
        <EmpName>John</EmpName>
        <Dept>HR</Dept>
        <Location>Ohio</Location>
        <Designation>Associate</Designation>
    </Employee> 
    <Employee>
        <EmpID>0002</EmpID>
        <EmpName>George</EmpName>
        <Dept>IT</Dept>
        <Location>California</Location>
        <Designation>IT Engineer</Designation>
    </Employee> 
    <Employee
        <EmpID>0003</EmpID>
        <EmpName>James</EmpName>
        <Dept>Fin</Dept>
        <Location>NewYork</Location>
        <Designation>Auditor</Designation>
    </Employee>
    </Office>
```

The above output I need to generate by using the POwerShell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: The input XML file doesn't organize employees correctly; they're all "mixed together" under Office and though they appear grouped to our eye, there's nothing that specify which values should be grouped together.

Here's a script that converts your first file into your second, based on the assumption that the employee elements under  in the first file always appear in the same order and are always grouped together.

```
[xml]$curXml =  Get-Content test.xml

$empNode = $curXml.FirstChild.CloneNode($true)
$curXml.FirstChild.RemoveAll()

$newNode = $curXml.CreateElement("OfficeName")
$newNode.InnerText = "NEWOFFICE"
$n = $curXml.FirstChild.AppendChild($newNode)

$newNode = $curXml.CreateElement("OfficeRegNuM")
$newNode.InnerText = "1234"
$n = $curXml.FirstChild.AppendChild($newNode)

$newNode = $curXml.CreateElement("OfficeAddress")
$newNode.InnerText = "Building 001"
$n = $curXml.FirstChild.AppendChild($newNode)

foreach ($child in $empNode.GetEnumerator())
{
    if ($child.Name -eq "EmpID") {
        $newEmp = $curXml.CreateElement("Employee")
        $n = $curXml.FirstChild.AppendChild($newEmp)
    }
    $n = $newEmp.AppendChild($child.Clone())
}

Write-Host $curXml.InnerXml
Set-Content -Value $curXml.OuterXml -path testOutput.xml
```

Comment: The output file you shared is what I want , However the node is not the first child in my file.

Comment: I have edited the output file. Can you help on this. In the new output file <Employee> is not the first child

Comment: I posted one more similar query for XML file correction. I am sure you can help me there. The question is at https://stackoverflow.com/q/61096126/13179395

Comment: Manish, I'll look at the other query soon. Can you mark the one above here as answered please?